# Code won't return value?

Tags: c#

(I'm a beginner to both programming and this website. In advance: I appologize if I make any mistakes in terms of using this website the wrong way.)

I'm trying to use the following code for a mandelbrot program. I need the program to return 'n' but when I debug I get an error message saying the program doesn't have a suitable static main method:

> Error 1   Program 'c:\Users\Alain\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Mandelbrot\Project1\Project1\obj\Debug\Project1.exe'
>   does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point C:\Users\Alain\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Mandelbrot\Project1\Project1\CSC    Project1

Though I can clearly see there is a 'main' method in the code.
does anyone know what the problem might be?

my code (C#):

```
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class formule
    {
        public static int main()
        {
            double f = new double();
            double x = new double();
            double y = new double();
            double a = new double();
            double b = new double();
            int n = new int();
            double max = new double();
            double schaal = new double();
            double afstand = new double();

            x = 0.5;
            y = 0.8;
            n = 0;
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
            // max = invoer 3
            //schaal = invoer 4
            afstand = 0;

            while (afstand <= 2) 
            {
                a = (a * a - b * b + x);
                b = (2 * a * b + y);
                afstand = Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));

                n++;
            }

            return n;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `main()` needs to be `Main()`. The error message (that you only added later to the question) is pretty clear on that - when the compiler gives you an error or a warning, it's there for a reason and you should read it carefully.

Since I added this as a comment already to another answer, here's how you can declare `Main()` in a C# program: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx If you follow the links in that top-level article, you can find the various alternative `Main` declarations that the compiler will accept.

As a comment on your code (not strictly related to the question): you don't need to write `double f = new double();` and then assign a value separately (although you can). You can just write:

```
double f = 0;
```

`double` and `int` are value types and declaring a value type creates an instance implicitly. You still have to assign some kind of value to them before you can read them (otherwise the compiler will complain about trying to use an uninitialized variable).

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the main entry-point of a C# program must be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

- Main  is declared inside a class or struct. Main must be static and it should not be public. (In the earlier example, it receives the default access of private.) The enclosing class or struct is not required to be static.
- Main  can either have a void or int return type.
- The Main method can be declared with or without a string[] parameter that contains command-line arguments. When using Visual Studio to create Windows Forms applications, you can add the parameter manually or else use the Environment class to obtain the command-line arguments. Parameters are read as zero-indexed command-line arguments. Unlike C and C++, the name of the program is not treated as the first command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive, so you must pay attention to case, always.

`Main` and `main` are two different methods.

C# needs `Main()` as its entry point. `main()` is just another method.

Incidentally, this is a choice of the C# compiler, not .NET. The low level assembly code defines it with the .entrypoint directive.

```
 .method public static void Main() cil managed {
   .entrypoint
```

If you write your own .NET assemblies with MSIL, you can decide to use main or foo as your "main" program.

Another interesting caveat, you can actually return a value that is used in Main(). Watch Main() call itself. Now I don't recommend this, but it demonstrates Main is just another function, albeit registerd as the entrypoint for the module.

```
  static int Main(string[] args)
  {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
              args = new[] {"foo"};
              Main(args); // recursively call Main()
              Console.WriteLine("2nd Main executed");
              return -1; // Parent main returns
        }

        // Child Main() finishes the work
        Console.WriteLine("Main finished");

        return 0;
  }
```